# Adding Data Files to PyInstaller Not working

Tags: python, pyinstaller, sciter

I am trying to bundle a file named `home.htm` with a executable made using PyInstaller.
I use this command : `py -3.7 .\pyinstaller\pyinstaller-4.3\pyinstaller.py --hidden-import pkg_resources --windowed --add-binary="sciter32.dll;." --add-data="home.htm;." -i C:\Users\USER\Downloads\152238-1.ico --onefile .\main.py` But still it fails to load the `home.htm` file.
My Code :-

```py
import sciter
import sys
import os

wd = sys._MEIPASS
file_name = os.path.join(wd, "home.htm")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    frame = sciter.Window(ismain=True, uni_theme=True)
    frame.load_file(file_name)
    frame.expand()
    frame.run_app()
```